# GWT in its web-mode throws StatusCodeException but in its hosted-mode , it's working perfect

Tags: gwt

I am new to this forum.

Actually I have an issue here regarding my application which is
hibernate+struts based application. Recently we have decided to
integrate GWT into our application. We are using gwt 1.5.3 build.

We have set up everything exactly as we find in documentation and
various blogs. Yeah I am now in a very nervy state as gwt in its web-
mode is treating me in a very embarassing manner. But it is compiling
and working perfectly fine in its hosted-mode and everything works
fine as we expected and designed. When I try to integrate GWT with our
application i.e. running in tomcat (http://localhost:8080/myapps/example.do?
reqCode=takeMeToGWT&userId=12&templateId=10). The gwt page is loaded
partially and in the midst it throws an exception i.e.
StatusCodeException. This doesn't happen when I run the gwt
application in hosted-mode ( http://localhost:8888/com.myapp.gwt.MyApp/Home.html
) .

I am using Intellij Idea 8, struts 1.3 ,hibernate 3 and tomcat 5.5 .

Expecting your responses at the earliest possible time.

Thanking you
B Roshnikanta Sharma
broshnikanta@gmail.com

Comment: Why did you chose to use GWT 1.5.3 over 2.0.3. When is that "recently" that you decided to integrate? I think GWT 2.0 is out for a few months now...

Comment: Do you know what code is causing the exception? If so, posting that would be helpful. If not, maybe compile with --style=pretty and try stepping through the resultant JS in Firebug.